# Consider categories MAT and N, the additive monoid of natural numbers. Are the functors between MAT and N square matrices?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I am pretty new to category theory and in some examples of categories there was the Mat category with natural numbers for objects and real matrices as morphisms (an n by m matrix between objects n and m) as well as the N additive monoid one-object category. I want to apply the definition of a functor between these two categories and I think I can somehow prove that a functor is basically a square matrix, but I am not sure how. Can someone help me show this?

Comment: I was thinking that any functor from M to MAT must map the one object in M to some natural n in MAT. Then morphisms in M from the generator say g are brought to n by n matrices. From there though I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

This is not unique to $MAT$. The monoid $N$ you mention is the free monoid on a single object. That means, pretty much by definition, that a functor $N\to M$ to any monoid $M$ whatsoever is the same data as the choice of an element $m\in M$. Now, a functor $N\to C$, where $C$ is any category whatsoever, is, by definition of functor and since $N$ only has one object, the same as a choice of an object $X$ in $C$ and a function $N(*,*)\to C(X,X)$. This function needs to be compatible with the composition, which amounts precisely to saying that it is a morphism of monoids. So, a functor $N\to C$ amounts to a choice of an object $X$ in $C$ and a monoid morphism $N\to C(X,X)$ (since the hom set of endofunctors in a category is always a monoid). But $N$ is the free monoid on one object, so the data for a functor $N\to C$ is precisely a choice of $X$ in $C$ and $x\in C(X,X)$. If you apply this to $N\to MAT$, you see that it is, indeed, the same information as the choice of a 'size' $n$ and a square matrix of that size.